# Trying to sort a multidimensional array, by a sub-value with special characters

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, collation

I used to have a PHP array containing a list of countries:

```
$countries = array(
  'AX' => 'Åland Islands',
  'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
  'GB' => 'United Kingdom'
);

$collator = collator_create('en');
collator_asort($collator, $countries, Collator::SORT_STRING);
```

Obviously this list is much shorter for this example, but the sorting here worked. I expected and got:

- Afghanistan
- Åland Islands
- United Kingdom

However, I needed to add more data, and it became multidimensional:

```
$countries = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Åland Islands',
    'code' => 'AX'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Afghanistan',
    'code' => 'AF'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'United Kingdom',
    'code' => 'GB'
  )
);

usort($countries, function($a, $b){ return $a['name'] <=> $b['name']; });
```

It sorts every other country in the list, but gives me this:

- Afghanistan
- United Kingdom
- Åland Islands

I cannot for the life of me work out how to sort this correctly. I realise that no collator is being called or applied in it's current state, but is there a way to make the collator work in a multidimensional environment?

Comment: I should say though, in countries that uses the letter Å, it is usually the last in the alphabet, like here in Norway it is character no. 29. And when sorting stuff it is usually A-Å, so for me it would be very natural to look for it at the bottom of a list like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a possible fix based on your initial approach:

```
usort($countries, function($a, $b) {
  $collator = collator_create('en');
  $arr = array($a['name'], $b['name']);
  collator_asort($collator, $arr, Collator::SORT_STRING);

  return array_pop($arr) == $a['name'];
});
```

For optimal performance on long lists, you may want to instantiate $collator only once outside the scope of the anonymous function, though.

Comment: This works great, and retains the Collator which I was keen to do. I've done some quick performance testing and it doesn't appear to slow the script down at all. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it suits your needs. Note that there's no need here to preserve the keys of $arr. So, you can replace `collator_asort()` with `collator_sort()` and `array_pop($arr) == $a['name'];`with `$arr[1] == $a['name'];` It should be slightly faster.

Comment: Error _Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated_. Use this instead `array_pop($array) == $a['name'] ? 1 : -1` for ascending. And for descending, use `array_pop($array) == $a['name'] ? -1 : 1`

Answer (score 3):

In the case of multidimensional array, we can define a custom sort function using `collator_compare()` function:

```
$collator = new Collator('en');
usort($countries, function($a, $b) use ($collator) {
    return $collator->compare($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the *"country list"* without `Collator` you should convert all words with *accented* characters into its `ASCII` presentation(e.g. `Å` to `A`) by using `iconv` function:

```
usort($countries, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp(iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $a['name']), iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $b['name']));    
});

print_r($countries);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Afghanistan
            [code] => AF
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Åland Islands
            [code] => AX
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => United Kingdom
            [code] => GB
        )
)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this actually places Åland Islands **before** Afghanistan in my code. However, I could do with retaining Collator for i18n purposes